# how to delete all repo except specific repo files under /etc/yum.repos.d

Tags: linux, bash, find

under `/etc/yum/repos.d` we have the following repo

```
mng.repo
vrtf.repo
dbNM.repo
```

sometimes users create other repo under  /etc/yum/repos.d and this make mass because yum conflicts

so we want to delete all other files but except the repo files

```
mng.repo
vrtf.repo
dbNM.repo
```

so we can use like , but this syntax not completed and need help about

```
find /etc/yum.repos.d -type f -not -name 'mng.repo'  vrtf.repo dbNM.repo -delete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bash with rm, with extended globbing:

```
shopt -s extglob
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/!(mng.repo|vrtf.repo|dbNM.repo)
```

The `!(...)` wildcard expands to files that do *not* have any of those filenames. This is not a recursive solution -- it works only on files that are directly in /etc/yum.repos.d.

Using `find`:

```
find /etc/yum.repos.d/ -type f ! -name mng.repo ! -name vrtf.repo ! -name dbNM.repo -delete
```

The expression looks for files anywhere under /etc/yum.repos.d that do not have any of the listed names.